# C# / OLE DB: Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, oledb, ms-access-2010

Here's my relational database (.accdb):

(sorry, not enough reputation, can't post image)

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B11KxyqILxOoVFR5OFBBbEplS0k

Code with error:

```
cmd3.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Transaction ([InvoiceNum], [ItemID], [Quantity]) " +
                     "Values (?, ?, ?)";

cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceNum", invoiceNumber);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemID", itemID);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", item.GetQuantity());

cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery(); //ERROR: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement
```

If I INSERT INTO Transaction2 instead, it works.

Working code:

```
 cmd3.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Transaction2 ([InvoiceNum], [ItemID], [Quantity]) " +
                     "Values (?, ?, ?)";

cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceNum", invoiceNumber);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemID", itemID);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", item.GetQuantity());

cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I think the problem has something to do with 'Transaction' having relationships with 'Invoice' and 'Item'.

Please Help!

Comment: if the error is ERROR: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement can't be a relationships problem. Check the Value of the parameters before insert.

Comment: What is the error message exactly? I'm going to guess it's because `Transaction` is a reserved word.

Comment: Marc B, Transaction is a reserved word on Sql Server, but this is Ms Acces. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335. Anyway, is a bad table name for any database...i guess.

Comment: NOTE: is a reserved word on Access 2010!!! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845663(v=office.15).aspx#daidxsqlt_z. Change the table name will do the trick!

Comment: Transaction is a reserved word. Changing the table name did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word TRANSACTION is a reserved word in SQL. Use a different name for your table.